This is a C program meant to run the string characters in the array
void str1(char *str1, int size);

int main()
{
    char *str[2][15] = {
        "You know what",
        "C is powerful"
    };
    char *ptr;

    ptr = &str[0][0];
    str1(*ptr, 2);

    return 0;
}

void str1(char *str1, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            printf("%s", *str1[i][j]);
    }
}

I am expecting it to print out each string character in the array after each execution of the for loop. I am still trying to understand how arrays, pointers and functions work in C programs.

What problem are you having with this program? Note that %s is for strings, %c is for characters

char *str[2][15] ... hmmm, why do you want to keep 30 pointers to char (30 strings) in memory; and then supply only 2 (the other 28 get a NULL)?

Suggestion: turn on the maximum level of warnings you have available, and mind the warnings

Hey jide, You are doing great, my own way understanding of what is that the declaration char *str[2][15] is incorrect. It should be char *str[2] since you are initializing it with a 2D array of strings.

@DerekRoberts char *str[2] declares an array of 2 pointers to char. With char *str[2][15] a 2D array of pointers to char is declared and when initialized as shown with the string-literals, the addresses are assigned to str[0][0] and str[0][1] all other pointers are initialized all zero (NULL). As written you would pass str[0][0] or str[0][1] as the parameter to the str1() function.

Ajayi, understand you can use as many levels of pointer indirection as you want. You can use char *str[ROWS][COLS] = {{ "You know what", "C is powerful" }}; and then simply call str1 (str, ROWS, COLS); where you have void str1 (char *(*str1)[COLS], int rows, int cols) and loop i < rows and j < cols and test if (str1[i][j] != NULL) printf ("%s\n", str1[i][j]); Of course you #define ROWS     2 and #define COLS    15 up top.

Let's point out the issues in your code one by one.
This
char *str[2][15] = ....

will create a 2D array of type char *. The in-memory view would be something like this:
str:
+--------------------------------------------+
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--------------------------------------------+

Each member of this array is a pointer to char type.
Because str is a 2D array, the way you are trying to initialize it is incorrect. Compiler must be throwing error on it.
After that, you are doing this:
ptr = &str[0][0];

The type of str[0][0] is char * and type of &str[0][0] is char ** and you are attempting to assign it to ptr whose type is char *. You must be getting assignment to char * from incompatible pointer type char ** error on this.
After that, you are doing:
str1(*ptr, 2);

The type of ptr is char * and the type of *ptr is char. The type of the first parameter of str1() is char *.
In str1(), the first parameter str1 is of type char * and in printf() you are passing *str1[i][j] which is wrong.
Looks like you want to create an array of 2 members of char * type and initialize them by pointing them to the strings providing in the initializer. You should do it like this:
char *str[2] = {"You know what", "C is powerful"};

It is a 1D array of type char *. The in-memory view would be something like this:
str
[0]  [1]
+---+---+
|   |   |----------> "C is powerful"    
+---+---+
  |
  +----------------> "You know what"

Create a pointer and make it point to str:
char **ptr;

ptr = str;

Why is the type of ptr char **?
Because when you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few exceptions to this rule), and the type of the first element of the str array is char *, so the type of a pointer to its first element will be char **. Hence, the type of ptr is char **.
The str1() function prototype will be:
void str1(char **str1, int size);

and its definition will be:
void str1 (char **str1, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%s\n", str1[i]);
    }
}

Putting these all together:
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char *str[2] = {"You know what", "C is powerful"};
    char **ptr;

    ptr = str;
    str1 (ptr, 2); // Instead of passing 2, you can also do sizeof (str)/sizeof (str[0])

    return 0;
}

void str1 (char **str1, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", str1[i]);
    }
}

Output:
You know what
C is powerful

Hope this helps.

You can cast any pointer(except function pointer) to char* or void*, so it's actually not a incompatible pointer error

You need an introductory C book, there is no shortcut for that.
Some of the things it will cover are:
char s1[] = {'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'}; declares an array of characters. Because you specify all the array elements, C can count that and use that as the size of the array. If you don't, or you want it bigger, you can put the size in []. In C a string is an array of characters with '\0' as the last character, so this is one.
char s2[] = "a string"; declares another array of characters the same as above. When you specify a string with "", the compiler adds a '\0' at the end.
char *s3 = "a string'; declares a pointer to a string. The compiler allocates an array somewhere automatically, which should not be modified.
char *s4[] = {"a string"}; declares an array of pointers to strings (a single pointer in this case). You could assign it to a string pointer (char *x = s4[0];), or replace it with another pointer (s4[0] = s3;).
C tries to treat arrays and pointers similarly, because efficiency was much more important when it was designed. Sometimes you can use an array where you need a pointer, e.g s3 = s2; will assign a pointer to the array s2 to s3. You can also use a pointer as an array sometimes, e.g printf("%c", s3[2]); will print the 's' from the string.
If you don't keep track of that and understand when and where it happens it can lead to problems.
A C introduction will also tell you that in C a 2D array is really a 1D array with math to compute the array indexes.
int a1[3][3]; declares an array with 4 elements, accessed with two indexes. C does not check the array indexes, so a1[0][0] is fine, but a1[3][3] will cause a problem (indexes must be less than the size, so 0 to 2), but is allowed. a1[3][0] is the same as a1[1][0] (and can be extended up to a[8][0]the same asa1[2][2]`), but is confusing and should be avoided.
There's a lot more to be covered, because C arrays and pointers have a lot more subtleties than most other languages, but that should give you a feel for what to expect.

"declares a pointer to a string"  I strongly suggest you amend this to "string literal" and perhaps point out that you don't modify this memory.

Or rather "shouldn't attempt to modify this memory."

@Chris I was describing a string as "this is what the format is", regardless of its storage, and didn't want to pile on too much at once, but I'll add that.
